# air-interface independent protocol

Tags: gps, network-protocols, rfc

I would like to know if there is any protocol document that specifies "air-interface independent"/ AI2 protocol like ISO/IEC documents or RFCs. In particular for GPS domain.

Thanks in advance...

Regards,
Aadishri

Answer (score 0):

You can start by reading the [SUPL spec](http://www.openmobilealliance.org/Technical/release_program/supl_v1_0.aspx) provided by OMA